# CakePHP 3.6 default directory permission for Cache file engine

Tags: caching, cakephp-3.0, file-permissions

I am using `Cake\Cache\Engine\FileEngine` for cache in my CakePHP 3.6 app. I would like to define **cache directories permissions**. I have tried using 'mask' in Cache config, but it only affects the files that the cache is creating, not directories.

It looks like cache directory permissions are always set to `drwxr-xr-x`, which makes it a problem for me, because in such a case only the owner can delete files in these directories. I need a directory be writable by group as well, not only the owner.

**Question: Is it possible to define what file permissions should the cache directories be created with by CakePHP?**

**My current config:**

```
'_cake_model_' => [
    'className' => 'Cake\Cache\Engine\FileEngine',
    'prefix' => 'myapp_cake_model_',
    'path' => CACHE . 'models/',
    'serialize' => true,
    'duration' => '+1 years',
    'url' => env('CACHE_CAKEMODEL_URL', null),
    'mask' => 0666,
],
```

**/tmp/cache listing:**

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data   www-data   4096 Feb  7 12:15 models/
-rw-rw-rw- 1 www-data   www-data 396020 Feb  7 12:07 myapp_cake_routes_route_collection
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data   www-data   4096 Feb  7 12:05 persistent/
```

**Note:** I understand I can manually `chmod` the directories, but they will get recreated with the default permissions after deleting them, so it's not the best fix.

Answer (score 0):

The cache engine uses `775` for creating folders:

- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.7.3/src/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php#L390**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.7.3/src/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php#L433**

However, this isn't the final mode, `mkdir()` will apply your current umask on this, which probably is `022`. IIRC `mkdir()` will effectively do this to figure the actual mode:

```
mode & ~umask & 0777
```

which will result in `755`, ie `rwxr-xr-x`.

In other places CakePHP temporarily unsets the current umask to avoid this, not sure why exactly the engine doesn't use `umask()` here too (maybe the possible multithreading problems would be more prevalent here, IDK), you may want to open an issue over at [**GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues) for clarification.

As a (temporary) workaround you could for example [**create a custom/extended cache engine**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#creating-a-cache-engine) that overrides `FileEngine::_setKey()` and `FileEngine::_active()` and applies `chmod()` from there. Or maybe create the folders yourself before the cache engine tries to create them, for example in your bootstrap...